# Python Selenium: Extracting dynamic tables from nested classes

Tags: python, html, selenium, css-selectors

I'm trying to retrieve data from two tables whose data gets updated every `0.5` seconds, the table is present in the nested class structure. I have used Selenium's `driver.find_element_by_xpath` and tried to get the data by a sequence of `div[contains(@class,one)]/div[contains(@class,two)]...` but in vain.

I tried its other available methods and searched for other resources but could not get any close.

Any leads! Here's the HTML code:

```
<body>
<div class="one"> 
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three">

            <!--- First table -->

            <table class="Jan">
                <thread>...</thread>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='cost'>100 </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='cost'>86 </td>
                    </tr>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    <tr>
                        <td class='cost'>56 </td>
                    </tr>           
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>...</tfoot>
            </table>

            <!--- Second table -->

            <table class="Feb">
                <thread>...</thread>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='cost'>-856 </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='cost'>-8986 </td>
                    </tr>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    <tr>
                        <td class='cost'>-9856 </td>
                    </tr>           
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>...</tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create list of class name like this and then iterate to find number of table rows and then get the text.

`listclass=['Jan','Feb']`

**Code**:

```
listclass=['Jan','Feb']
for item in listclass:
    tablerows=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='"+ item + "']/tbody/tr")
    data=[row.get_attribute("textContent") for row in tablerows]
    print(data)
```

Output in a list:

```
['100', '86', '56']
['-856', '-8986', '-9856']
```

---

The other option you can use pandas and `read_html()` and load data into `dataframe`.

**Code**:

```
driver.get("url here")
time.sleep(3)
page=driver.page_source
dfs=pd.read_html(page)

for df in dfs:
    print(df.T)
```

**Console output:**

```
     0   1   2
0  100  86  56
     0     1     2
0 -856 -8986 -9856
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your input. I tried the first method and I receive `NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: window was already closed` error. Is it because the data has already been changed in the short span?

Comment: You need to wait for the data to load properly.Put some wait to load data.You do one more thing to check if there any iframe above table elements?

Comment: Can you share your url?

Comment: The URL is internal to my account. There are no iframes. Data is as it is. Let me go through it once more. I'll update you.

Comment: No error now, but I receive no output either. Blank. Anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: @meW : Just updated the `for loop` instead of text i have updated  `get_attribute("textContent")` can you check now?